# Route constraint worked in Rails 5, not working in version 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had a route constraint that would serve my React app when a certain sub domain was in my URL:

```
class ReactAppContraint
  def matches?(request)
    (request.subdomain.size > 0 and request.subdomain == "app")
  end
end


Rails.application.routes.draw do

  constraints(ReactAppContraint.new) do
    #root "react#index" # not allowed in Rails 6
    get '*path', to: 'react#index'
  end

end
```

Now in rails 6.x when I locally visit:

```
app.mydomain.com:3000
```

The route constrain is ignored, even though the conditions have been met.

Also, I am not allowed to have 2 root definitions.  I guess I don't need it since I am using a wildcard so that's fine but curious wh